# How can I share prisma2 studio with my teammates?

Tags: prisma2

I'm using prisma2 service in expressJS graphQL API. I want to use prisma2 studio page as a admin panel, and I want to share prisma2 studio page with my teammates, who are not programmer. Because it is an admin panel that we can change db Data, I want to deploy with password system. Is is possible to deploy prisma2 studio page with password? Is there any service that allows people to enter website only if he has a password?

Answer (score 0):

running

```
prisma studio -h --experimental
```

allows the use of the prisma server only on local host.
you can connect it to your server ip address by changing the @prisma/cli/build/index.js file,replace

```
"http://localhost:${this.port}" to https://<ipaddress>:${this.port}
```

. But this is still an experimental feature it's unsafe to make this changes

Comment: I want to deploy it as an website and I'm worrying that someone else can access the website. Is is possible to deploy it with an access password?

Answer (score 0):

This best way to autogenerate Prisma Admin and share it with your client is using my [Prisma admin React component](https://paljs.com/prisma-admin). With this, you can add your models as normally react component in your frontend project